# Set the endpoint for boto3 SQS

Tags: python, amazon-sqs, boto3, elastic-mq

Our application uses amazon's SQS for message queues and we use elasticMQ for testing/staging; elasticMQ is a message queue server that is fully compatible with SQS. Since the majority of our application is in java, we can run embedded elasticMQ in our tests or staging, switch over our queue endpoints to point to elasticMQ and voila, everything works very nicely and we don't touch our production queues.

That being said, we have some of our application written in python - which uses boto3 for SQS requests. Since elasticMQ can also be run as a standalone application I was wondering if it was possible to switch the endpoint from the default url (sqs.region.amazonaws.com:80) to something else (localhost:9324) in boto3. I've scoured the documentation and SO but haven't been able to identify if what I'd like to do is even possible.

Comment: SQS passes a `QueueURL` in requests. I wonder if you can modify it to point to an alternate location? You might also be able to override the list of regions to define one that has different endpoints.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass in the `endpoint_url` to the client / resource constructor.

```
import boto3

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
emq = boto3.resource('sqs', endpoint_url="http://www.foo.com")
```

[docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client)