# botot3 with sqs: the address 'QueueUrl' is not valid for this endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

I am trying to the get queue url from a SQS queue. I have read about other posts [Set the endpoint for boto3 SQS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666494/set-the-endpoint-for-boto3-sqs) and [boto3 sqs incorrect url when not specified endpoint url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663622/boto3-sqs-incorrect-url-when-not-specified-endpoint-url) but it is still puzzling why the code is not working.

My region being `us-east-1` and the endpoint seems to be the correct one https://queue.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyMessages (legacy)

```
import json
import boto3

from datetime import datetime


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S %p")

    sqs = boto3.client('sqs', region_name="us-east-1")
    #get queue url using queue name
    queueurl = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName='MyMessages')
    print(queueurl)
    
    for x in range(5):
        sqs.send_message(
            QueueUrl=str(queueurl),
            MessageBody=current_time
        )
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(current_time)
    }
```

**Error**

```
Test Event Name
sendMessage

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidAddress) when calling the SendMessage operation: The address {'QueueUrl': 'https://queue.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyMessages', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '10fea792-29fa-5484-9bc0-fbb6ad9320b7', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '10fea792-29fa-5484-9bc0-fbb6ad9320b7', 'date': 'Tue, 27 Dec 2022 05:27:05 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '322'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}} is not valid for this endpoint.",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "requestId": "ba1f3c72-6180-4308-ad12-0bc6b02c3793",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 18, in lambda_handler\n    sqs.send_message(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: ba1f3c72-6180-4308-ad12-0bc6b02c3793 Version: $LATEST
{'QueueUrl': 'https://queue.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyMessages', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '10fea792-29fa-5484-9bc0-fbb6ad9320b7', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '10fea792-29fa-5484-9bc0-fbb6ad9320b7', 'date': 'Tue, 27 Dec 2022 05:27:05 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '322'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAddress) when calling the SendMessage operation: The address {'QueueUrl': 'https://queue.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyMessages', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '10fea792-29fa-5484-9bc0-fbb6ad9320b7', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '10fea792-29fa-5484-9bc0-fbb6ad9320b7', 'date': 'Tue, 27 Dec 2022 05:27:05 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '322'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}} is not valid for this endpoint.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 18, in lambda_handler
    sqs.send_message(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 719, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)END RequestId: ba1f3c72-6180-4308-ad12-0bc6b02c3793
REPORT RequestId: ba1f3c72-6180-4308-ad12-0bc6b02c3793  Duration: 1108.64 ms    Billed Duration: 1109 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 65 MB  Init Duration: 275.81 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response of `sqs.get_queue_url` is

```
{
    'QueueUrl': 'string'
}
```

So modifying like this will work.

```
    response = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName='MyMessages')
    queueurl = response['QueueUrl']
```